# i keep getting the "list' object has no attribute 'find_element'" error whenever i try to use find_element after using find_elements

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am new to web scraping and I wanted to use the find_element function to find a specific element after already using find_elements, but whenever I try to use it I keep getting this error: list' object has no attribute 'find_element'.

here is the code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible"
driver.get(url)
crucible_content = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-gamereport-list.trn-gamereport-list--compact")))
game_report = crucible_content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group")
group_entry = game_report.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group-entries")
```

i have tried these methods:

```
1.group_entry =WebDriverWait(game_report, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group-entries")))
2. for group_entry in game_report:
        group_entry = game_report.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group-entries")
 
3. group_entry = game_report.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group-entries")[1]
```

unfortunately, I still get the same error. it would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: apparently `game_report` is a list

Comment: do you know how to access a specific item within the game_report list? I want to get group entry and get the nested elements from that item. @TalhaTayyab

Comment: nops I do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `find_elements()` to get a **list** of all matching elements, then loop over that list and call `find_element()` on each item.

```
game_reports = crucible_content.find_elements(...)
for game_report in game_reports:
    group_entry = game_report.find_element(...)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately, it still shows me the same error @John Gordon

Comment: @internshiphopeful That shouldn't be possible.  You must have made some mistake copying my example, or you edited your code but forgot to save the changes, or something like that.

Comment: @internshiphopeful Double check that you are using the correct names in the correct places.  `game_reports` looks a lot like `game_report`, and `find_elements` looks a lot like `find_element`.

Comment: i was able to implement it, but I got a new error saying it can't find the element. is it because its dynamic?

Comment: @internshiphopeful I have no idea.  We'd have to see your full code, and the full html of the page, to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting a list i.e game_report , try to iterate over the list and find the element the element.

```
for element in range(len(game_report)):
     print(game_report[element].text)
```

You simply can't call find_element method on the list

Comment: what do I do if I didn't want to print the element but instead wanted to locate the element in order to find other elements that would be under it. e.g if I wanted to access element 1 I  want to do: element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "element1")

Comment: try this - game_reports[element].find_element(By. CLASS_NAME, "element1")

Comment: my bad, i meant to say that I only need to access only one HTML element within game_report. that way I can go from there and access elements under it